# Embedded ActiveMQ Keeps Restarting Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, activemq-classic, ioexception

So I have a tomcat server (tomcat6) that I am running a Spring stack on. As part of the stack, I have an ActiveMQ embedded server that I'm using to process messages. I have configured the broker in my spring context like this:

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" 
    p:brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" />
<bean id="jmsCachedConnectionFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory" 
    p:targetConnectionFactory-ref="jmsConnectionFactory"
    p:sessionCacheSize="100" />

<amq:broker id="broker" useJmx="false" persistent="false">
    <amq:transportConnectors>
    <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    </amq:transportConnectors>
</amq:broker>

<bean id="jmsDestination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="EDS.PUSHES" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsMessageProducerTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate" 
    p:connectionFactory-ref="jmsCachedConnectionFactory"
    p:defaultDestination-ref="jmsDestination" />

<jms:listener-container container-type="default" 
    connection-factory="jmsCachedConnectionFactory" task-executor="pollingExecutor"
    acknowledge="auto" prefetch="5" destination-type="queue" cache="none" concurrency="50-100">
    <jms:listener destination="EDS.PUSHES" ref="pushMessageConsumer" method="onMessage" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

The pushMessageConsumer is just my class that reads the messages from the queue through the onMessage method.

Periodically, the jms server reports an EOF Exception:

```
012-08-09 14:50:02,891 [ActiveMQ Connection Executor: tcp://localhost/127.0.0.1:61616] 
    WARN  org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory  - Encountered a 
    JMSException - resetting the underlying JMS Connection

javax.jms.JMSException: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:49)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onAsyncException(ActiveMQConnection.java:1841)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onException(ActiveMQConnection.java:1858)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.onException(ResponseCorrelator.java:126)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onException(WireFormatNegotiator.java:160)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor.onException(InactivityMonitor.java:265)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.onException(TransportSupport.java:96)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:269)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:227)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:219)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:202)
    ... 1 more
2012-08-09 14:50:02,908 [pollingExecutor-4] WARN  
    org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  - Setup of JMS 
    message listener invoker failed for destination 'EDS.PUSHES' - trying to recover.  
    Cause: The Session is closed
```

Then it reboots Tomcat, restarting my whole application. I tried adding an ioExceptionHandler by changing the broker definition and adding a bean using the DefaultIOExceptionHandler:

```
<bean id="ioExceptionHandler" class="org.apache.activemq.util.DefaultIOExceptionHandler">
    <property name="ignoreAllErrors"><value>true</value></property>
</bean>

<amq:broker id="broker" useJmx="false" persistent="false" 
    ioExceptionHandler="#ioExceptionHandler">
  <amq:transportConnectors>
    <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61616" />
  </amq:transportConnectors>
</amq:broker>
```

But it continues to keep on restarting the tomcat server when the EOF exception happens. Am I missing something in the configuration?

Comment: I have no clue what causes this IO/EOF exception. One thing comes to mind, is this AMQ instance local to your tomcat server? Then just switching from tcp to the vm protocol (vm://brokername), so it won't touch the network stack. A long shot, I know.

Comment: Just wanted to note that since I switched over to this, I haven't seen this issue, so that does appear to work.